# RIA platform like Netbeans RCP

Tags: java, netbeans, frameworks, ria, rcp

Does anyone have any experience with a really good RIA platform.  I'm going to begin developing an application, and I intend to use Netbeans RCP for the thick client.  I'd also like to create a RIA version of the same app.  I've looked around for a RIA framework that rivals what you can get with the Netbeans RCP, and really haven't found one.  My requirements are as follows.

- Modular - I would like to be able to add and remove features without recompiling
- Out of the box features - I'd like to have feature out of the box that are similar to Netbeans RCP (or most any other RCP), such as a menu system built in, a windowing system (allowing docking and remembering where windows were between sessions), Authentication and Authorization support out of the box, as well as the "Options' pane support (I really like how I can add amodule, and have that module expose options through the standard "options" dialog).
- Actions and commands - I'd like to be able to handle actions from other modules without needing to couple the action to the other module.
- I would like to deploy the app through GlassFish, but that's not a deal breaker.
- Modern - the framework should use the latest standards, and I'm planning on moving to J2EE7 as soon as I can, so the platform must be actively updated to support such a migration.
- I'm willing to pay, but the license must not be "per server" or "per instance"
- Java isn't a must but I'm planning on using java for the rest of the app (services layer) and the Netbeans RCP front end.

I've been a .net developer for the last 6 years, and have just recently looked into the world of java, and I'm really amazed at the rich community, I thought .net had a large open source community, but the java one is orders of magnitude bigger.  I don't know of anything even close to the Netbeans RCP in the .net community, let alone a RIA version.

I've looked at a few frameworks, but most of them seem to be mostly libraries that you can use to build applications, I really don't want to spend the time and maintanance cost to build the infrastructure listed above.  Things I've looked at are....

- Tepestry
- "SmartClient"
- GWT
- Wicket

These all seem to be good building block, but I want an out of the box solution.  The application will be mostly CRUD operations, but I will also be streaming video through the app, as well as handling alerts and events from the server.

Thanks for any advice

Joshua

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse with the GWT plugin is fairly easy to get running out of the box.  Step through the GWT tutorial first and you'll be ready to go.  I realize you've already looked at GWT but the Eclipse plugin simplifies a lot of grunt work.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. GWT Eclipse plugin simplifies compilation, depoloying and running them (Jetty). It also has App Engine support.